# Comma after "perhaps" at the end of the sentence

Tags: creative-writing, writing-style, academic-writing, punctuation

Which one is correct?

- I. "This is the worst day in this month, perhaps the worst in my life."
- II. "This is the worst day in this month. Perhaps the worst in my life."

Should we offset the adverb *perhaps* with a comma from the independent sentence preceding it if it bears an emphatic meaning like this?

Comment: The independent clause sounds rather unnatural (I'd expect 'This is the worst day I've had this month' unless you were referring to trading performance etc). However, only sticklers would object to your second variant on grammatical grounds (sentence fragments used sparingly in informal contexts are considered far more acceptable nowadays, and the one here adds a more substantial dramatic pause). // I'm happy with the deletions in I'. "This has been the worst day I've had this month, perhaps the worst in my life."

Comment: Everything, just about, is OK in speech. However, worst day in this month is not really idiomatic. We say: the worst day this month.

Answer (score -1):

The second example is technically wrong, as the second sentence in it isn't complete and doesn't have a verb. The first is OK, but I would probably use a dash or a colon:

> This is the worst day in this month — perhaps the worst in my life.

If the 2nd clause is more of an aside a comma is fine, e.g. if the sentence continued:

> This is the worst day in this month, perhaps the worst in my life, and I'm ready to quit.

Comment: As an aside, the first clause is clunky and I'd at least drop the "in": e.g. "this is the worst day this month"

Comment: 'Technically wrong' is ill-defined. Here, many gifted writers accept and use the sentence fragment when used sparingly and judiciously. "Hello, Jill." ... "Oh, hi, Bob." ... "Do you know where Sue keeps the sugar?" "In the tea-caddy!"

Comment: "worst day **in** this month"? Buzzer for me.

Comment: @Lambie umm read my comment. OP asked about commas, not wording, which if you weren’t racing to downvote me you’d have noticed I addressed separately.

Comment: The second one is not technically wrong. It can reflect dialog or speech, which does not always include neatly formed sentences with an SVP structure.

Answer (score -1):

The first one violates comma rules.  One option is to replace the comma with 'and' (a conjunction). However, I too like the use of '-' (dash) as a way to suggest an afterthought of for emphasis.

Sources:
https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/commas/

[https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/#:~:text=%20Dashes%20%201%20To%20set%20off%20material,to%20the%20meaning%20of%20a%20sentence...%20More%20](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/#:%7E:text=%20Dashes%20%201%20To%20set%20off%20material,to%20the%20meaning%20of%20a%20sentence...%20More%20)

Comment: You should explain the comma rules, not merely assert that they are broken.

Comment: There are seven rules identified in the source that I cited, and it follows none of them.  In fact, a source was included for anyone interested in all seven comma rules that includes examples.  It would also be redundant since the prior contributor who answered pointed out the comma rule error.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418563)